# Python requests with login credentials

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login to a URL & download the content then parse, the URL needs username & password to login.

using below gives below errors:

```
import requests
url = 'https://test/acx/databaseUsage.jssp?object=all'
values = {'username': 'test_user',
          'password': 'test_pswd'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values, headers=headers)
print r.content
```

Error log output from above code:

tried with below values as well , without any success

values = {'Login': 'test',
          'Password': 'test',
          'Log in': 'submit'}

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> <!-- must be first; see SD5930 -->
    <title>Test URL login</title>
    <!--meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="/nl/logon.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="setFocus();">
    <div id="htmlContent">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
          <div class="login_frame">
            <div class="header_login">
              <img src="/nl/img/logo.png" alt="Test URL" />
            </div>
            <div id="form-main">
              <!--[if lte IE 7]>
              <div class="warning"><b>Warning</b>: your browser isn't supported by Test URL. <br/>To be able to use Test URL to its full potential, you need to update your browser.</div>
              <![endif]-->
              <form method="POST" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="loginForm" action="/nl/jsp/logon.jsp">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />

                <input type="hidden" name="target" value="/acx/databaseUsage.jssp?object=all">

                <p class="input first">
                  <label for="login">Login</label>
                  <span>
                    <input id="login" name="login" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p class="input">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <span>
                    <input id="password" name="password" tabindex="2" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
                  </span>
                  <br />
                </p>
                <p class="memorize submit last">

                    <input id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" class="checkbox" tabindex="3" type="checkbox" />
                    <label class="checkbox" for="rememberMe">Keep me logged in</label>

                  <button id="validate" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </p>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="footer" class="dashboardFooter">
        <div id="footerContent" class="nlui-pageWidth">
          <p>
          &copy; Test URL 2017
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function setFocus() {
        document.loginForm.login.focus();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image of login page

[image]

Comment: I hope you won't leave `password` hardcoded

Comment: Set the latest user agent.

Comment: If you are expecting `values` to be passed into input boxes, that's not how `requests` works

Comment: @AmitTripathi , user agent is just a warning , I tried with user agent but getting same error.

Comment: What user agent did you try?

Comment: @AmitTripathi please see the edited original post headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

Comment: can you login with your browser? do you see the warning?

Comment: login screenshot is useless better put real url so everyone could see this page and its code. Of course without real login/password we can't test it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to login successfully you'll have to submit the correct data to the correct URL. You can get those values from the HTML form, or by inspecting the network traffic in your browser. Also, you may want to gather any authenticated cookies.

- Make sure to use the correct URL. You can get that URL from the form's `action` attribute (if the form has no action it is submitted to the URL that hosts it). If you examine the form you'll see that it is submitted to: "/nl/jsp/logon.jsp".
- Make sure to include all required data. If the form contains hidden inputs they should be included in the POST data. It is important to submit all the form fields because they may contain essential data.
- You can use a [`Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object to store your cookies. This will collect and use cookies (and other parameters) across requests, and so you can access the site as an authenticated user.
- If you want to set or change headers you can use either the `headers` parameter or the `Session.headers` attribute - which wil use those headers for all requests. Usually changing the default User-Agent is enough, but some sites may expect more headers (a valid Referer for example).

---

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/nl/jsp/logon.jsp'
post_data = {
    'login': 'username', 
    'password': 'password', 
    'target':'/acx/databaseUsage.jssp?object=all', 
    'action':'submit'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'My user-agent'
    r = s.post(url, data=post_data)
    print(r.text)
```

If you still can't login you may have to use `Selenium`. Sometimes JavaScript is involved in the login process and `requests` doesn't run JavaScript code. It may be possible to reverse-engineer this process but it would be much easier/better to use `Selenium`.