# Download file generated by URl in Python

Tags: python-3.x, url, get

I am generating a URI for an API python using a GET request. I am authorizing using a username and password, and have admin privileges in the system.

I then try to extract the file from the URI using the following code:

```
r = requests.get(fileurl, allow_redirects = True)
```

However, this throws out a 401 Unauthorized code.
I have already provided my login credentials while generating an access token to be able to get to the file url. Do I also need to provide credentials while generating the file, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Does [Python requests with login credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836456/python-requests-with-login-credentials) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python requests with login credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836456/python-requests-with-login-credentials)

Comment: It doesn't - I still have the same 401 code